# My Reverse SSH Tunnel Does Not Work, What Am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: ssh-tunneling

I have access to an AWS host (C) from my PC (A). a firewalled host (B) cannot hit AWS, so I'm trying to create a reverse tunnel so my firewalled host can hit the AWS host.

ASCII Picture

```
     ssh connection A2B
  <<------------------- A       reverse tunnel B2C
B--------------------------------------------------->> C
  <<-------------------
```

Here's what I'm doing from A:

```
ssh -R4443:C:443 B:22
```

once connected to B, from B I telnet...

```
 telnet localhost 4443
```

I get **connection refused.**

I tried making C==google.com and still the same result, that's when I figured I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I tried the same thing and it works just fine; the connection is successfully established. Is there a firewall on host B that is blocking inbound connections  on the loopback interface?

Comment: Or on host C...

Comment: Wouldn't that same firewall block me going from A -> C ?